# Make part of kineticjs image not visible

Tags: image, kineticjs, mask

I have a image of a ship moving over a map. As it crosses under a bridge I want to make the part of the ship that passes under the bridge invisible.

At the moment I using a separate copy of the bridge that is placed as an image on top of the ship but this requires additional artwork to be created.

Ideally I want to simply specify an invisible polygon and any part of the ship image under the polygon becomes invisible thus leaving the bridge on the map intact.

Is it possible to hide a part of the ship image dynamically on a frame by frame basis in animated fashion?

Answer (score 0):

KineticJS only allows rectangular clipping regions.

A workaround:

You can use an off-screen canvas to clip out your bridge.

Then you can specify that off-screen canvas as the image source to a Kinetic.Image element.

```
var myClippedShipImage=new Kinetic.Image({

    image:myOffscreenCanvasElement,

    ...

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a separate image for the ship, i suppose a kinetic image on the same layer?
So you can easily use the inbuilt `.moveToTop()` function of KineticJs.

E.g. image of ship is like:

```
bridge = new Kinetic.Image({
    x: [..],
    y: [..],
    width: [..],
    height: [..],
    image: [..],
    id: 'bridge'
});
```

it goes like:

```
layer.get('#bridge')[0].moveToTop();
layer.draw();
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Gerard I have that part already working but it requires me to create the bridge image. I am hoping to avoid that by instead dynamically making part of my ship image transparent where the bridge is. see: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvcSxO3bsOU&list=UU1pRrrDqkTJ_MhA9P45AfLg